# Ninject dependency injection to provide roles and membership

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

Im trying to construct a Dependecy Injection of my user repository (entity framework), and using this to help create roles in my MVC web app. The membership provider seems to be working fine.

Web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>  
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="MyApp.Infrastructure.Concrete.CustomMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="MyApp.Infrastructure.Concrete.CustomRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

My Ninject module:

```
internal class MyNinjectModules : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUserRepository>().To<EFUserRepository>();
    }
}
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new MyNinjectModules());
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Cart), new CartModelBinder());

        ninjectKernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
        ninjectKernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);
    }
}
```

Custom membership provider:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private static List<User> Users = new List<User>();

    [Inject]
    public IUserRepository userRepo { get; set; }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        Users = userRepo.Users.ToList();
        return Users.Exists(u => u.Name == username && u.Password == password);
    }
}
```

Custom role provier:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private static List<User> Users = new List<User>();

    [Inject]
    public IUserRepository userRepo { get; set; }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        //Hardcoded roles for known users
    }
}
```

Authorize like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="SiteAdministrator")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    //controller
}
```

Ive not used Dependency Injection before, but i must bind my IUserRepository wrongly?? I get this error:

```
Error activating IUserRepository
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
   2) Injection of dependency IUserRepository into parameter userRepo of constructor of type AdminController
   1) Request for AdminController
```